# How to check whether a useState set (passed in props) is called in a Jest test?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, websocket, jestjs

I have a React component with the followings functions:

```js
const changeOrder => { a websocket request
};

const handleArrow = async () => {
    const res = await changeOrder(side, headingOrder, config);
    if (res !== undefined) setOrder(res);
};
```

`setOrder` is a set of a useState passsed in props

I want to test if the `setOrder` is call like this:

```js
// WebSocket Mock-up
let ws: WS;
beforeEach(async () => {
    ws = new WS("ws://localhost:8764", { jsonProtocol: true });
    new WebsocketClient("localhost", 8764);
    await ws.connected;
});
afterEach(() => {
    WS.clean();
});

describe("The ChangeOrderArrow component", () => {
    it("should render left arrow and can send a request to change the heading order", async () => {
        const setOrder = jest.fn();
        render(
            <ChangeOrderArrow
                setOrder={setOrder}
            />,
        );

        fireEvent.click(screen.getByTestId("left-heading-button"));

        const req: { request: RequestMessage } = (await ws.nextMessage) as { request: RequestMessage };
        const uuid = req.request.path.split("/")[2];

        expect(req.request.options.value).toEqual(359);

        act(() => {
            ws.send(responseChangeOrderArrow(uuid));
        });

        expect(setOrder).toHaveBeenCalled();
    });
});
```

Only the last line with `.toHaveBeenCalled` failed and of course I want that return true.

The returned jest error is:

```
expect(jest.fn()).toHaveBeenCalled()

    Expected number of calls: >= 1
    Received number of calls:    0
```

I checked that the condition `if (res !== undefined)` was met, when the `handleArrow()` is called.

Anyone have a lead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because the `setOrder` is after `await changeOrder(side, headingOrder, config);` in the `handleArrow()` function, I need in my test to wait like this:

```js
await waitFor(() => {
    expect(setOrder).toHaveBeenCalledWith(234);
});
```

Now the expect pass!